# C++ why template initilizer-list constructor allow the non-copyable object to be copied

Tags: c++

Consider the following code with template initilizer-list constructor:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
void f()
{
    std::cout << "main thread:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
}
class Z
{
    struct Y
    {
        virtual void call() = 0;
        virtual ~Y() {}
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Y> x;
    template<typename F>
    struct X : Y
    {
        F f;
        X(F&& f_): f(f_) {}
        void call() {f();}
    };
public:
    template<typename F>
    Z(F&& f):
        x(new X<F>(f))
    {}
    void operator()() {x->call();}
};
int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> task(f);
    Z z(task);
    z();
    return 0;
}
```

When the object `z` is initilized with `task`, the template `F` in the initilizer-list constructor of struct X is deduced to be std::packaged_task<void()>. The confusing thing is that the code is compiled successfully while std::packaged_task is non-copyable.

However when I use non-template constructor:

```
...
struct Y
{
    virtual ~Y() {}
};
struct X : Y
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> f;
    X(std::packaged_task<void()>&& f_): f(f_) {}
};
int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> task(f);
    std::unique_ptr<Y> p (new X(std::move(task)));
    return 0;
}
```

the code is failed to compile as expected, because the g++ compiler complains packaged_task
is non-copyable with the message "`packaged_task(const packaged_task&) = delete`".

So what happens in template initilizer-list constructor?

Comment: F is deduced to`std::packaged_task<void()>&`

Comment: @JeffGarrett Thanks for the correction, yes, the lvalue of T is deduced to T&. But why in template constructor `:f(f_)` can be initilized without the call of deleted copy constructor of packaged_task. In my understanding it should give the same compliation error as the second case.

Comment: You're not initializing a copy. You're initializing a reference with the object it's going to refer to.

Comment: @JeffGarrett You really hit the point. Indeed it just move the address of `task` to create reference instead of copy.